# Receive mails with Flutter

Tags: email, dart, flutter

I want to create an app with Flutter for which it is necessary to receive (and send) mails. Clients share information with eachother in a decentral way using i.e. Googlemail without using an own server. 
During my research I found several ways to send mails but no way to receive them since this seems to be not implemented yet in any package.

Flutter offers the option to use platform-specific code with platform channels ([flutter plattform-channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/)) which might be a solution. 
However I haven't tested this yet because I write the app for both iOS and Android which means that I'd have to do this for each java and Swift/Objective C.

Maybe someone here knows a better solution.

Comment: You need a mail server with a fixed IP address and a domain with the server registered as mail exchange to receive emails. A phone probably won't do here. You can access such a mail server using POP or SMTP protocol from your phone. If you want to send/receive using an existing mail server or mail service please clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. 
Yeah, i should really have clarified that earlier: 
I want to use existing mailhosters like googlemail for a decentral app using only mails for communication between the clients.

Comment: Do you want to use a specific one or any or all of them? What is the purpose. Do you want to build an universal mail client or do you want to sent some service mails for specific ocassions, ...?

Comment: What mail accounts would that use? Does each user need to provide his own or do you want to create a single one that everyone uses?

Comment: I want to create an app including foodshare, a noticeboard, etc without using a server. So I decided to use mails for every necessary communication between the clients. The user wont have to read this mails because the app just needs the information from it and creates posts based on the content.

Different mail hoster might be optional but I need at least one that works with my app. 

Each user has its own mail adress

Comment: Any provider that provides a REST API for email send and receive would be easy to use. You could try Google mail API using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis I'm not sure it's appropriate for your use case. You need to take care that nobody can use the email account you use for that to send spam. This can easily get you account shut down.

Comment: Thank you for the link, looks nice to me so far.  I think about creating the mailadress with a script and using it only with the app so that the user wont notice it. But i will keep that in mind